# Is chroot an example of application virtualization in Linux?

Tags: virtual-machine, chroot

I am not very certain about the concept of [Application/Process Virtualization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_virtualization).

To help with that, what are some examples  of application virtualization in Linux? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_virtualization#Description gives several examples of application virtualization in Windows.)

Is chroot such an example?

Are cgroup, namespace, and docker such examples? If not, why?

Thanks.

Comment: Your first link is broken.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27584/lightweight-virtualization-on-linux-with-user-isolation)

Comment: [Another possible duplicate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31136/lightweight-isolated-linux-environment)

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no.

## No

Docker is not virtualisation: It uses namespaces, chroot, cgroups, etc; **docker adds no extra virtualisation on top of Linux**. Therefore: as docker uses chroot, and is not virtualisation, then chroot is also not virtualisation. However is can be used for the same things.

This all depends on definitions, if virtualisation is how it works, then no, if it is what it dose then sort of.

## Yes

Unix including Gnu/Linux is a type of virtualisation (As is Microsoft's NT): The OS visualises the hardware. Each process gets to run as if on a dedicated hardware. (Plus inter-process communication etc.)

Comment: @rubberstamp, yes you can edit. I was being a bit sarcastic, as Tim knows this.

Comment: "Therefore as docker uses chroot, and is not then chroot is not" There must be some typo or grammar error…

Comment: I think the grammar is OK, but I have improved it, as it was a bit hard to understand (two implied words, may be hard no understand my English as a second language people).