# Does chroot need any special kernel support?

Tags: linux-kernel, chroot, cgroups, namespace

docker is said to be a steroid version of chroot.

Does chroot need any special kernel support, e.g. namespace, cgroup?

Does docker rely on chroot? I ask this because ["Docker is not virtualisation: It (as you know) uses namespaces, chroot, cgroups, etc."](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/510897/674)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`chroot` is implemented [by the kernel](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chroot.2.html), separately from namespaces and cgroups. Mount namespaces and `pivot_root` can be used to provide the same functionality as `chroot`; see [How to perform chroot with Linux namespaces?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/456620/86440)

Docker engine uses `chroot`.

Comment: Can chroot be similar to or replaced by some namespace?

Comment: Yes, see the update.