# Allow certain guests to execute certain commands

Tags: permissions, sudo, privileges

I would like to create a new user on some of my Debian/Ubuntu hosts that is able to update the server using the commands `apt-get update` and `apt-get dist-upgrade`, but I do not wan't to give them full sudo access to be able to do anything else. Is this possible? Perhaps there is a way to create a script that they can't edit but can execute, which will get executed as the root user?

Comment: See `man sudoers` and `sudo cat /etc/sudoers`.

Comment: Thanks @goldilocks I had always thought the sudoers file was just to allow people to be granted root access before.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`Sudo` and the `/etc/sudoers` file aren't just for granting users full root access.

You can edit the sudoers file with an existing sudo user, with the command `sudo visudo`

You can group the commands that you want to grant access to like below:

```
Cmnd_Alias SHUTDOWN_CMDS = /sbin/poweroff, /sbin/halt, /sbin/reboot
Cmnd_Alias UPDATE_COMMANDS = /usr/bin/apt-get
```

You can then give a specific user privileges to those commands like so:

```
[User's name] ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: SHUTDOWN_CMDS, UPDATE_COMMANDS
```

This can be seen in the image below[image]:

Now if you try `sudo apt-get update` or `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` those commands will execute **without asking for a password**. If you want to be prompted for a password, remove the `NOPASSWD` bit where you grant a user access to command groups.

If you try to run anything else as the `sudo` user, you will be prompted for a password and fail.

### References

- [Ubuntu Docs - Sudoers](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers)
- [How To Edit the Sudoers File on Ubuntu and CentOS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-edit-the-sudoers-file-on-ubuntu-and-centos)
- [Take Control of your Linux | sudoers file: How to with Examples](https://www.garron.me/en/linux/visudo-command-sudoers-file-sudo-default-editor.html)

Comment: Note that giving users the permission to run `apt-get`, or even merely `apt-get upgrade`, **gives them full root access**! Many upgrade scripts allow the interactive user to execute a shell, for example when a configuration file has changed. To be safe, restrict `apt-get` to certain commands, and force it to be non-interactive. See [Is it safe for my ssh user to be given passwordless sudo for `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205385/is-it-safe-for-my-ssh-user-to-be-given-passwordless-sudo-for-apt-get-update-an)

Comment: In my case I had to put the line after `%sudo ...`

Comment: Is there a way to do it just from command line?