# non-root user able to access network, power commands, by using groups?

Tags: linux, debian, network-interface, group

how to [add user ]to a network,and power [group],so that i dont have to use every time "sudo iconfig" or "sudo poweroff" {i remember that groups used in old linux box to control network and power, able to access b normal user}, i'm using debian now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allow certain guests to execute certain commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/215412/allow-certain-guests-to-execute-certain-commands)

Answer (score 3):

`sudo` is the easiest way to do this.  If typing a password every time is what bothers you, you can edit `/etc/sudoers` with `visudo` to make those two commands unpassworded for your sudo user.

`%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/ifconfig*, /sbin/poweroff`

If typing `sudo` in front of the command is what you object to, set aliases in your `~/.bashrc`.

`alias poweroff='sudo poweroff'`

`alias ifconfig='sudo ifconfig'`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add the user to any group to run some network command like `ifconfig` , the user can run the command as follow :

```
/sbin/ifconfig
```

or

```
export PATH=$PATH:/sbin
ifconfig
```

Comment: Can work for poweroff too :).

Comment: I think you're missing the point that what OP wants to do with those commands requires superuser permissions.  Yes, anyone can run them by specifying the full path, but the actual issue to be solved is that OP wants to run those commands without having to invoke sudo each time.

Comment: @sourcejedi it will not work for the poweroff command , it is an additionally information to the working answer

Comment: @Q23 Have you tried it?  poweroff works fine on both Stretch and Jessie.  Tested in VM.  Doesn't work over SSH or serial cable.

Comment: Good question.  I was in a Kali VM and figured that was close enough.  I don't have a Debian VM available at the moment but the poweroff command without superuser permissions failed for me on Kali and Ubuntu 14.04, and did work on Ubuntu 16.04.